# Can we disable AOP invocations?

Tags: java, log4j, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have AOP based loggin functionality with the following settings

Context xml configuration:

```
<bean id="performanceMonitor" 
class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor" />

<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allServiceMethods" 
            expression="execution(* com.eshop.sfweb.service.impl..*(..))" /> 
    <aop:pointcut id="allEpServices" 
            expression="execution(* com.service.catalog..*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="allServiceMethods" 
            advice-ref="performanceMonitor" order="2" /> 
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="allEpServices"
            advice-ref="performanceMonitor" order="2" />
    </aop:config>
```

Log4j properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorIntercept
or=${ep.perflog.level},PERFORMANCE 
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE.File=webAppRoot:WEB-INF/log/performance.log 
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE.threshold=DEBUG 
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d -- %-5p [%t | %F:%L] 
-- %m%n
```

Is there any way that I can disable the AOP invocations itself depending upon the enviroment?
I can disable the logging very easily but can I disable/enable the entire background process and invocations?

Please let if any clarifications are required.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Spring AOP, one quick way to enable or disable aspects could be to simply use Bean profiles.

Define a profile say `enableAOP`:
Wrap the aop:config in say a configuration file under the specific profile

```
<beans profile="enableAOP">
    <aop:config> <aop:pointcut id="allServiceMethods" 
    expression="execution(* com.eshop.sfweb.service.impl..*(..))" /> 
    <aop:pointcut id="allEpServices" expression="execution(* 
    com.service.catalog..*(..))" />
....
</beans>
```

Now, whichever environment you want the specific aspects enabled, just run with `enableAOP` profile on.

Comment: May I know which version of spring supports this profile attribute for beans? I tried in spring 2.0 but failing to parse spring bean xml.

Comment: Excellent answer. Curt, elegant and precise.

Answer (score 2):

it's been a while since this question was asked, but here is what I came up with for Spring 2:

Create an empty xml file (`aop-context-off.xml`) with an empty `<beans>` declaration.
Then create for example an `aop-context-enabled.xml` file with your AOP declaration.

Finally when importing the XML you could use :

```
<import resource="aop-context-${AOP_CONTEXT_SUFFIX:off}.xml" />
```

This will look for a system variable called AOP_CONTEXT_SUFFIX and if not found force the value to `off`.

So in the example above, by setting `AOP_CONTEXT_SUFFIX` to `enabled` it will load the `aop-context-enabled.xml`

So the switch being the system variable, you can easily Enable/Disable it at server start.